# Why we use 2pi for a sqaure wave in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I wanted to create a square wave signal with period of 1 second and a duty cycle of %30.

When I was looking at the MATLAB examples, I came up with these expression at the square function documentation;

`t = 0:1/1e3:0.07; y = square(2*pi*30*t,37)+randn(size(t))/10;`

Random noise is irrelevant, however I couldn't figure out why we call the square function with the **2*pi** argument?

What would happen if I just called the square function with 30*t parameter? Even there is another way to do what MATLAB documentation did, I want to know why they did it that way.

Thanks in advance for any explanition.

Comment: The reason the examples use 2pi is because these waves are often compared to sin waves, who's entire period happens at 2pi

Comment: The real answer is because that is how the person who wrote it decided to implement it. Could they have done it differently? Yes. But then someone would be asking "Why don't we have to scale the input by 2*pi, when that makes the most sense to me?"

Answer (score 1):

[square wave](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/square.html)

> generates a square wave with period 2π for the elements of the time
> array t

a period of 2pi means 1 complete cycles ends when `t = 2pi` not when t=1, to make t=1 have one cycle you have to convert 1 to 2pi, basically multiplying the entire timescale by 2pi.